# Pympler get memory usage of object

Tags: python, memory

I need help using [Pympler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pympler/0.1) and getting the memory usage of an object. I am using it like this:

```
from pympler import classtracker

myObj = SomeClass()
tr = classtracker.ClassTracker()
tr.track_object(myObj)

# Do stuff with object here

# Print stats
tr.create_snapshot()
tr.stats.print_summary()
```

This works fine and I get these results:

```
---- SUMMARY ------------------------------------------------------------------
                                         active      0     B      average   pct
  SomeClass                                   1    136.45 KB    136.45 KB    0%
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My question is how do I get the average number and put it in a variable? I can't find anything in the documentation. I'm running some tests and want to get the average over the lifetime of the tests. If you know of a way  to do that or if there is any other package I can use to accomplish what I want, please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the asizeof function, you don't even need to use classtracker (unless you are using some of the more complex functionality)

```
from pympler.asizeof import asizeof

class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []
    def append(self, i):
        self.list.append(i)

myObj = SomeClass()

myObj.append("Hello")
myObj.append("World")

print 'Sizeof myObj is {}'.format(asizeof(myObj))
```